# MYSQL joining subquery issue

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery

I have one table that has people's grades in it.

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
|  name   | grade1 | grade2 | grade3 |      datetime       |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
| person1 |     50 |     80 |    100 | 2015-05-05 12:00:00 |
| person1 |     60 |     43 |     88 | 2015-05-05 12:00:00 |
| person1 |     11 |     80 |     44 | 2015-05-05 12:00:00 |
| person1 |     64 |     75 |     37 | 2015-05-05 12:00:00 |
| person1 |     83 |     34 |     99 | 2015-05-05 12:00:00 |
| person2 |     45 |    100 |     95 | 2015-05-05 12:00:00 |
| person2 |     76 |     75 |     54 | 2015-05-05 12:00:00 |
| person2 |     68 |     53 |     66 | 2015-05-05 12:00:00 |
| person2 |     45 |     12 |     85 | 2015-05-05 12:00:00 |
| person2 |     75 |     78 |     55 | 2015-05-05 12:00:00 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+---------------------+
```

What I need to do is pull a person's grades for a specific day and then a string representing their pass/fail report from previous (up to 7) days.

The final result I would be looking for based off the table would be something like this:

```
+---------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+----------------+
|    report     |  name   | grade1 | grade2 | grade3 |    datetime    |
+---------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+----------------+
| pass:3 fail:2 | person1 |     50 |     80 |    100 | 5/5/2015 12:00 |
| pass:2 fail:3 | person2 |     42 |    100 |     95 | 5/5/2015 12:00 |
+---------------+---------+--------+--------+--------+----------------+
```

So my sql to get the first part is pretty simple:

```
SELECT *
FROM Grades.grade_table gt
WHERE gt.datetime = '2015-05-05 12:00:00'
```

The second part of my query looks like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT('fail:',SUM(CASE WHEN pass_fail = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),' pass:',SUM(CASE WHEN pass_fail = 'pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) trend_data
FROM (
    SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN ((grade1+grade2+grade3)/3) >= 65 THEN 'pass'
        ELSE 'fail'
    END AS pass_fail
    FROM Grades.grade_table gt
    WHERE gt.name = 'person1'
    LIMIT 7
) trend_data
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT 
(
  SELECT CONCAT('fail:',SUM(CASE WHEN pass_fail = 'fail' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),' pass:',SUM(CASE WHEN pass_fail = 'pass' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)) trend_data
  FROM (
    SELECT
    CASE
      WHEN ((grade1+grade2+grade3)/3) >= 65 THEN 'pass'
      ELSE 'fail'
    END AS pass_fail
    FROM Grades.grade_table gt
    WHERE gt.name = original_data.name
    LIMIT 7
  ) trend_data
) AS trending_data, original_data.*
FROM
(
  SELECT *
  FROM Grades.grade_table gt
  WHERE gt.datetime = '2015-05-05 12:00:00'
)
```

I keep getting cant find original_data.name in where clause, but I thought that would come through since it's in a separate select which is aliased.

Comment: I've created a sql fiddle here if it helps at all:
sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac6d0/10/0

Comment: I've updated my answer. It should meet your requirements now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to rebuild your schema and create a simple query of what you need.

**SQLfiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/74eb5e/61

Query for getting success and fail:

```
SELECT name AS 'Name',
    CONCAT(
      'Fail: ',
      CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN (grade1+grade2+grade3)/3 <= 65 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(20)),
      ' Success: ',
      CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN (grade1+grade2+grade3)/3 > 65 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS CHAR(20))) AS 'Report',
      NOW() AS 'Report date'
FROM grade_table gt1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM grade_table
       WHERE name = gt1.name
       AND gradedate > gt1.gradedate
       ORDER BY gradedate ASC) < 7
GROUP BY name;
```

**Edit 1:**

New code and updated SQLfiddle meets your requirements (last seven days of each person's fails and successes).

**Edit 2:**

This is basically a more complex problem that is well described here:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

Generally you can't just go easily with a LIMIT for such clause, because you want to limit per group (`GROUP BY name`). However you can use something like this to get top N records per group:

```
SELECT name, gradedate
FROM grade_table gt1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM grade_table
       WHERE name = gt1.name
       AND gradedate > gt1.gradedate
       ORDER BY gradedate ASC) < 2
```

It will check if particular record in group has (`COUNT(*)`) less than two records with greater(newer) date. It simply means it can be only that record and optionally one greater from it.

I've updated final solution so it should match your needs now.
Please note that **solution provided is not very efficient**, although it scales up with N possibilities of name.
I recommend You to read up the blog provided as there're greater examples and some great comments below the article that would be to hard to elaborate on here in a short time.

Comment: That's close to what I'm looking for. The reason I can't look for just last 7 days, is that some students results are from greater than 7 days ago, some aren't. I need up to last 7 instances of student data regardless of how far back date is.

Comment: Please check the solution, I think we're there now. You can try to test it with less than 7 days in `WHERE` clause so that you don't need to produce more sample data.

Comment: Awesome, I wasn't even close in my approach... :( 

Thanks for your solution and the provided blog link!